# Search Person Information by there email id using Graph API Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to Search the person basic information like email,name,address etc by passing there email id on graph API of facebook. But its not working and its returning me the message

> "error": {
>         "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 200
>      }

I am passing url like below-

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=EMAIL_ID&type=user&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Please suggest me how can I able to search information by passing email id in graph api. and also if I logged out and then logged in back then my this access_token is not working. Do I need to get different access token each time? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? I mean, first you get the email from the user and then searching for the user with that id again?